# Append values from one column to another JSON column in the same dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have some data in dataframe which looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------+
|       Noun| Pronoun|  Adjective|Metadata                        |
+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------+
|      Homer| Simpson|Engineer   |{"Age": "50", "Country": "USA"} | 
|      Elon | Musk   |King       |{"Age": "45", "Country": "RSA"} |
|      Bart | Lee    |Cricketer  |{"Age": "35", "Country": "AUS"} |
|      Lisa | Jobs   |Daughter   |{"Age": "35", "Country": "IND"} |
|      Joe  | Root   |Player     |{"Age": "31", "Country": "ENG"} |
+-----------+--------+-----------+--------------------------------+
```

I want to append values from another column(say `Adjective`) into the `Metadata` column. So that the final dataframe would look like this:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|       Noun| Pronoun|  Adjective|Metadata                                                    |
+-----------+--------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Homer| Simpson|Engineer   |{"Age": "50", "Country": "USA", "Adjective": "Engineer"}    | 
|      Elon | Musk   |King       |{"Age": "45", "Country": "RSA", "Adjective": "King"}        |
|      Bart | Lee    |Cricketer  |{"Age": "35", "Country": "AUS", "Adjective": "Cricketer"}   |
|      Lisa | Jobs   |Daughter   |{"Age": "35", "Country": "IND", "Adjective": "Daughter"}    |
|      Joe  | Root   |Player     |{"Age": "31", "Country": "ENG", "Adjective": "Player"}      |
+-----------+--------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please suggest how this can be implemented.

Comment: What is the data type of column `Metadata`?

Comment: it is a json object.

Comment: yes, String in dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your column `Metadata` contains JSON strings, you can first convert it to `MapType` with `from_json` function, then add the columns you want using `map_concat` and finally convert again to JSON string using `to_json`:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "Metadata",
    from_json(col("Metadata"), lit("map<string,string>"))
).withColumn(
    "Metadata",
    to_json(map_concat(col("Metadata"), map(lit("Adjective"), col("Adjective"))))
)

df2.show(false)

//+-----+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
//|Noun |Pronoun|Adjective|Metadata                                            |
//+-----+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
//|Homer|Simpson|Engineer |{"Age":"50","Country":"USA","Adjective":"Engineer"} |
//|Elon |Musk   |King     |{"Age":"45","Country":"RSA","Adjective":"King"}     |
//|Bart |Lee    |Cricketer|{"Age":"35","Country":"AUS","Adjective":"Cricketer"}|
//|Lisa |Jobs   |Daughter |{"Age":"35","Country":"IND","Adjective":"Daughter"} |
//|Joe  |Root   |Player   |{"Age":"31","Country":"ENG","Adjective":"Player"}   |
//+-----+-------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

This also can be done using a conversion to StructType instead of MapType but map is more generic in this case.

Comment: This answer worked but what if i want to add another json object within the `Metadata` column. so that the final value in `Metadata` will look like `{"Age":"50","Country":"USA","Adjective":"Engineer", "Tags": {"t1": "v1", "t2": "v2" }}`

Comment: @UserASR hey were you able to achieve this, I have very similar requirement. Could you please help me